# error while installing kylo specific services for nifi

Tags: installation, apache-nifi, kylo

I am trying to install kylo 0.8.4.
There is a step to install kylo specific components after installing Nifi using command,

`sudo ./install-kylo-components.sh /opt /opt/kylo kylo kylo`
but getting follwing error.

`Creating symlinks for NiFi version 1.4.0.jar compatible nars
ERROR: spark-submit not on path.  Has spark been installed?`

I have spark installed.

need help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The script calls `which spark-submit` to check if Spark is available. If available, it uses `spark-submit --version` to determine the version of Spark that is installed.

The error indicates that `spark-submit` is not available on system path. Can you please execute `which spark-submit` on the command line and check the result? Please refer to the screenshot below for expected result on Kylo sandbox.

[image: Checking spark-submit location]

If `spark-submit` is not available on the system path, you can fix it by updating the `PATH`variable in `.bash_profile` file by providing the location of your Spark installation.

As a next step, you can also verify the installed version of Spark by running `spark-submit --version`. Please refer to screenshot below for an example result.

[image]

Comment: I have varified this and got the same output. Still it is giving the error.

Comment: You can update the `~/.bash_profile` to ensure that the path is available to all shells for the user.